# Import images from self-hosted to WordPress.com

Tags: url-rewriting, images, import

I'm trying to migrate my self-hosted WP blog to WordPress.com, images included.

Originally images were hosted on various image-hosting websites, but I've used [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-linked-images-to-gallery-v01/) to cache and upload them to my self-hosted WP media library. Now posts have image tags in this format:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/2033_l.jpg" alt="" />
```

I've exported my blog to XML, and used the import tool on WordPress.com. The blog is imported fine, and all images have been added to WordPress.com media library.

However, image urls in each post still link to my self-hosted (old) blog.

[I've contacted their support regarding this issue](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/importing-doesnt-change-image-urls?replies=2#post-821502), and they say I have to change each of the 650~ image urls manually.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I can do a *search & replace* on the exported XML file, but there must be some easier way of importing the urls correctly.

Comment: Close-voted as *off-topic*. Questions about wordpress **.com** are out of scope, for practical reasons (code can't be altered; can't install Plugins, can't access DB, etc.)

Comment: @Chip Bennett My question was about what to do *before* importing to .com, of course.

Comment: The thing is, I've never seen what you're describing happening for images that are *actually attached* - that is, images that have been added as attachment post-types. Are you *sure* that the Plugin you used actually adds the erstwhile external images to the WP DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually used [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-linked-images-to-gallery-v01/) to download and cache all images locally, and replace all links to the local ones.

Answer (score 0):

At .com, you can't use plugins or access the database to run queries to change the URLs. So yes, export the XML, find/replace and then reimport the XML file.